# Tension in vertical circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

A stone is whirled in a vertical circle tied at the end of  a string. What is the tension in string when the stone is at the highest position?
Is it less than the weight of the stone??

Comment: Hi Nishimya and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Yep, draw a free body diagram.  Remember that the force of gravity as well as the tension will be acting on the stone.